# Long vacuums in redshift

Tags: python, database, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to run `VACUUM REINDEX` for some huge tables in Redshift. When I run one of those vacuums in SQLWorkbenchJ, it never finishes and returns a connection reset by peer after about 2 hours. Same thing actually happens in Python when I run the vacuums using something like this:

```
conn_string = "postgresql+pg8000://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s" % (db_user, db_pass, host, port, schema)
conn = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine(conn_string,
                                       execution_options={'autocommit': True},
                                       encoding='utf-8',
                                       connect_args={"keepalives": 1, "keepalives_idle": 60,
                                                             "keepalives_interval": 60},
                                               isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT")
conn.execute(query)
```

Is there a way that either using Python or SQLWorkbenchJ I can run these queries? I expect them to last at least an hour each. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: check that the tables are not locked (check locks). run your vacuum from a linux server or something with a more stable connection

Comment: @JonScott Hi! I'm actually running the python script it from a linux server and i know the tables are not locked because i actually see the VACUUM REINDEX running from the AWS console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

You might need to add a mechanism in your python script to retry when the reindexing fails, based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html

> If a VACUUM REINDEX operation terminates before it completes, the next VACUUM resumes the reindex operation before performing the full vacuum operation.

### However...

Couple of things to note (I apologize if you already know this)

- Tables in redshift can have N sort keys (columns that data are sorted by) and Redshift supports **only 2 sorting styles**

  - **Compound:** You are really sorting
    based on the first sort column and then on the second, ...
  - **Interleaved:** The table will be sorted on all sort columns (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve), some people would choose this style when they are not sure how the table will be used. However, it comes with a lot of issues on its own (More solid documentation here https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-compound-and-interleaved-sort-keys/ where compound sorting is generally favored)

### So how does this answer the question?

- If your table is using compound sorting or no sorting at all VACUUM REINDEX is not necessary at all, it brings no value
- If your table is using interleaved, you will need to first check whether you even need to re-index?. Sample query

  ```
  SELECT tbl AS table_id,
     (col + 1) AS column_num, -- Column in this view is zero indexed
     interleaved_skew,
     last_reindex
  FROM svv_interleaved_columns
  ```
- If the value of the skew is 1.0 you for sure don't need REINDEX

### Bringing it all together

- You could have your python script run the query listed in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_INTERLEAVED_COLUMNS.html to find the tables that you need to re-index (maybe you add some business logic that works better for your situation, example: your own sort skew threshold)
- REINDEX applies the worst type of lock, so try to target the run of the script during off hours if possible
- Challenge the need for interleaving sorting and favor compound

Comment: I know it has been a while, but I'm marking this as correct  because it made me revisit my entire process for automated maintenance. I eventually discovered that the connection reset because of a company firewall issue, however, this explanation made me explore rebuilding some sortkeys and their types.